# Header mini-cart doesn't refresh when click browser's back button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I have problem with my header's mini cart. The issue is that when I add a product to the cart and then click the back button on any browser, the mini cart on the header doesn't refresh and subtracts the numbers of items that I added before.

I have other websites running woocommerce with same themes and works correctly.

Please I need your help! What could be happening?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to look at this- > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431164/preserve-dynamically-changed-html-on-back-button

Comment: When you click on the back button, do you refresh the page again?

Answer (score 1):

Clicking the back button right after visiting a new page mostly doesn't refresh the page. I dont think its an issue from mini-cart as the page might be loaded through cache. Its just the way browsers work.  you will have to make sure the page is refreshed.