# Loosing dynamic content when navigating back in the browser

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, browser-history

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431164/preserve-dynamically-changed-html-on-back-button). I am loosing ajax updates when navigating back on the browser... I want to know if there a better solution to this problem in ASP.NET MVC (the other answer suggests storing filter value in a hidden input and redoing the updates `onLoad`)

**This is my scenario:**

I am working on an e-commerce website. When user comes to the home page, he would see a filter and some advertisements:

[image]

The user then uses the filter to refine his search, say he would type *shoe* and clicks on Go. The Go bottom would send an ajax request to the server and the new advertisements are updated through ajax:

[image]

The user clicks on one of the ads and navigate to the ad details page... now if he presses the back button on the browser, he would come back to the home page but will loose the search result which was done by ajax.

Comment: Would it not be possible to allow the user's selected ad or ad choice to be stored in session?

Comment: Yes, I could use the session.

Comment: The simple solution is to make a normal post to a GET method (so you are making a redirect), rather that using ajax call.

Comment: Otherwise you could look at modifying `window.history` (using `history.pushState()`) to add a item for `.../YourMethod?search=shoe`

Comment: Thanks a lot @StephenMuecke